# Export out list of users and user types in Portal

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I'm trying to export a list of Portal users and their user types. This is the code I'm trying to use but getting an error regarding the `user.LicenseTypeId` entry:

```py
import csv 
from arcgis.gis import GIS

gis = GIS("https://test.esri.com:7443/arcgis", "username", "password", verify_cert=False)

outputFile = r"C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"

users = gis.users.search('*',  max_users=1000)

with open(outputFile, 'w', newline='') as ResultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(ResultFile)
    header = 'Username', 'Type', 'Email'
    wr.writerow(header)
    for user in users:
        UserRow = user.username, user.LicenseTypeId, user.email
        wr.writerow(UserRow)
```

Comment: What is the precise and full error (including line number) you see when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: Hi there: I receive this:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [2]:
Line 15:    UserRow = user.username, user.LicenseTypeId, user.email

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in __getattr__:
Line 9461:  raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'LicenseTypeId'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I don't know if it's an available property of the user class but have you tried `user.licenseTypeId` in stead of `user.LicenseTypeId`?